# Why some thieves don't have a city name in Money Heist?

Tags: money-heist

I could understand that some thieves are outsiders, and therefore they don't have a city name. That would include e.g. Benjamin. But then the question is why Marseille who is an outsider as well does have one?

On top of that for example Mathias <strike>doesn't</strike> didn't  have a city name even though he is inside the bank. One could say that he joined later. But so did Manila and she has a city name.

So…what is the key?

---

Also, I am not sure about the people who are melting the gold in the basement, but I guess we never heard their names.

Anyway, the only logical thing would be to give all of them city names if their identity is supposed to be hidden as much as possible.

Comment: It’s a fun show but you shouldn’t look too hard into it or expect rigorous consistency.

Comment: Marseille is not an outsider. He was part of the heist in the heist during the concert. So he is probably close to Berlin and the Profesor. He acts as the Profesor's trump card in case of trouble, so his position is quite important. We only don't know why he was not part of the heist at the Royal Mint.

Answer (score 3):

Mathias unexpectedly took a more prominent position as hostage overseer, due to unforeseen difficulties and absence of team members who got hurt and needed to recover or died. Originally, he was only supposed to be a nameless faceless smelter but they simply needed another person up top.

Notice how Mathias does not check in with the Professor, or join in team discussions. He is a rank down from them, and not part of the gang. I guess you could call him a subcontractor in that sense.

Also note that Mathias might not be his real name. He entered the heist as a supposed hostage who gets roped into working for the gang, so "Mathias" might be his cover identity as a believable person. If he was called e.g. Cairo, they couldn't pass him off as someone who is not part of the gang, breaking the illusion of having hostages as workers.

Benjamin and his crew are a late addition to the party. Not unexpected (there was a plan for it), but not part of the inner circle either. They were not part of the pre-heist planning phase.

Everyone with a city name was there for the initial planning phase, was trained in a multitude of skills to use during the heist, and is aware of (most of) the plans.
The non-city-named characters are not in on the big picture plan, only have their own skills and need direct instructions and handholding since they don't know the larger picture.

Comment: [this comment contains a tiny spoiler for last episode] After rereading this answer I consider it good and accept. Although it may be worth updating since we know from the last episode that Mathias 1. got city name 2. is very likely really named Mathias.